# Php move_uploaded_file function not working properly

Tags: php, html

I have a form where i have an input type as below:

```
topic image: <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

After that, i saved what i got in a variable:

```
$image=$_POST['pic'];
```

Then, i used the move_uploaded_file function but it is not working, here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   move_uploaded_file($image,'images/'.$image);
}
```

So, i want the file to be saved at a folder i want called "images" but it doesn't work. Could someone help me and explain me why?

Comment: You need to use `$_FILES` when working with file-uploads. Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: 1. `$_POST` is not the correct superglobal to access/manipulate file data, use `$_FILES`. 2. Make sure that you have `enctype= multipart/form-data` in your form. 3. `move_uploaded_file()` function call is wrong. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn the code [basics](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).
You should use the `$_FILES` super global for uploading files to your server. It is an associative array of uploaded file items and some of their properties.

Also you must add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your HTML form.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
topic image: <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //This is not a good file upload code sample. You have to improve it.
   $image=$_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];
   $imageName = $_FILES["pic"]["name"]
   move_uploaded_file($image,'images/'.$imageName );
}
?>
```